# PS Cmdlet does not write to the console

Tags: powershell, azure

I have this Cmdlet:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "AzureServiceBusQueue")]
public class GetAzureServiceBusQueue : Cmdlet
{
 protected override void EndProcessing()
 {
    string connectionString = string.Format("Endpoint=sb://{0}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={1};SharedAccessKey={2}", Namespace, SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessKey);
    NamespaceManager nm = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    WriteObject(nm.GetQueues(), true);
 }
}
```

Did the Import and ran the Cmdlet with required params.
I see nothing in the output console.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these variables `Namespace, SharedAccessKeyName, SharedAccessKey` initialised before? If not, I think you get `nm == null` thus no queues and no output.

Comment: I changed the connectionstring and hardcoded the values, still nothing